# Save images with filenams from list with Python

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I have a list of URLs that point to images. I want to save these images with filenames contained in the URL. So far I am able to either save all the images with incremental filenames (not what I want) or save one image with a filename taken from the URL (not what I want).

The URLs look like this:

```
http://foto.munchmuseet.no/fotoweb/cache/5018/Arkiv/G0003-02_20151201.t565f114c.m2400.tif.pv.xHYHOucgy.jpg
```

The regex to extract filenames (G0003-02_20151201) looks like this:

```
fn = re.findall('(?<=Arkiv/)(.*?)(?=\.t)', urlstr)
```

The code to save the images looks like this:

```
imgData = "./images/"
try:
    os.makedirs(imgData)
except:
    pass
iimage = 0
for urls in url:
    try:
        f = open((imgData + '{}.jpg'.format(iimage)),'wb')
        f.write(requests.get(urls).content)
        f.close()
        iimage += 1
    except Exception as e:
        print("\n{} {}".format(e,urls))
        pass
```

What I want is to replace `iimage` with the values from the list generated from the regex for each URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one approach using `os.path.basename` with `str.split`.

**Ex:**

```
import os
import requests

imgData = "./images/"
try:
    os.makedirs(imgData)
except:
    pass

for url in urls:
    try:
        f = open((imgData + '{}.jpg'.format(os.path.basename(url).split(".")[0])),'wb')
        f.write(requests.get(url).content)
        f.close()

    except Exception as e:
        print("\n{} {}".format(e,urls))
        pass
```

---

```
import os
url = "http://foto.munchmuseet.no/fotoweb/cache/5018/Arkiv/G0003-02_20151201.t565f114c.m2400.tif.pv.xHYHOucgy.jpg"
print(os.path.basename(url).split(".")[0])
# -->G0003-02_20151201
```